# Is it possible inserting pdf format image in a reportlab generated pdf document?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I do not think. It is just to be sure that I need to save in png, jpeg,  etc ... format the images or graphs before inserting in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDF can contain images, but PDF isn't an image format. You need to save images as images, in an image format (PNG, JPG, etc.).

Comment: Ah thank you for your answer, now I can move to other issues !